# Get currency symbol in block

Tags: magento-2.1, currency

everybody!

In header on my store I need to display a symbol of current currency. In my custom block I inherited from **\Magento\Directory\Block\Currency** and added following code:

```
class Currency extends \Magento\Directory\Block\Currency
{
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCurrentCurrencySymbol()
    {
        return $this
            ->_currencyFactory->create()
            ->load($this->getCurrentCurrencyCode())
            ->getCurrencySymbol();
    }
}
```

This is work good for me, but when I added additional currency (Russian Ruble) in en_US locale function returned NULL.

I found temporary solution, but I not sure that this good idea.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$currencies = $objectManager
    ->create('\Magento\CurrencySymbol\Model\System\CurrencysymbolFactory')
    ->create()
    ->getCurrencySymbolsData();

return $currencies[$this->getCurrentCurrencyCode()]['displaySymbol'];
```

Tell me, please, how I can solve the issue.

Magento 2.1.7

Comment: You should not use objectManager directly in files. You should use dependency injection as Magento 2 coding standards.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Where I can read about this?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. Hope you will get your answer

```
    <?php 
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterfa‌​ce'); 
    $currencyCode = $storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode(); 
    $currency = $objectManager->create('Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFact‌​ory')->create()->loa‌​d($currencyCode); 
    echo $currencySymbol = $currency->getCurrencySymbol(); 
    ?>
```

Comment: Abhishek, your code is the same as my first variant in the question

Comment: Did you try my code?

Comment: Yes, of course - it return null too. I added symbol tag in /vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Data/en.xml file and it works, issue not happens. But it's right solution?

Comment: But modifying the core library isn't good. In the further update it'll be lost